# #define for a success or failure

Tags: c

I am using a API that has a macro for success which is "NT_SUCCESS". However they don't have one for failure. So normally I have to do this.

```
if(something failed)
    return !NT_SUCCESS;
else
   return NT_SUCCESS;
```

Having the !NT_SUCCESS I don't think is very readable. So I decided to do this:

```
#define SUCCESS NT_SUCCESS
#define FAILURE (!NT_SUCCESS)
```

EDIT =============================

```
#define ENT_NOERR 0 /* No error */ 
#define NT_SUCCESS ENT_NOERR /* synonym of ENT_NOERR */
```

This is how NT_SUCCESS is declared, Would it still be ok to do what I have done.

Would that be ok?

Many thanks for any suggestions,

Comment: I have just edited my post. To show how NT_SUCCESS is declared. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, the `#define` is OK.  It is up to you to use it properly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would add parentheses for good measure, but otherwise you should be OK:

```
#define FAILURE (!(NT_SUCCESS))
```

This is "just in case", to prevent bad definitions such as `#define NT_SUCCESS 1+1`.  Of course, no sane implementation would do this, so your definition should be okay too.  But it can't hurt to be paranoid. :-)

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest to put the FAILURE define in parenthesis:

```
#define FAILURE (!NT_SUCCESS)
```

Comment: What difference would adding parentheses do? Thanks

Comment: It's arithmetically safer and insures it will always be evaluated in the order you specify.

Answer (score 2):

that would be ok

Comment: While this may answer the question, it is better to explain more of the reasoning behind your statement to help others understand

Answer (score 2):

This can not possibly be correct.  Surely you are supposed to return some kind of error code that gives the caller a chance to find out why it didn't work?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that logically negated value of `NT_SUCCESS` is an indication of failure?

Comment: Yes, that would indicate a failure.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it actually depends. It's a little unusual for you to return the same error values as an API you're *calling*. The only times I can see this would be required is if either:

- you're actually returning a value back from a callback initiated within the API.
- you're replacing code in the API so have to follow the same rules.

It may be that NT_SUCCESS is 0 but a failure can be indicated by any other integer. That means that !NT_SUCCESS is *not* the only value that means failure.

Of course, you're free to pass back from *your* API whatever values you wish, I wouldn't necessarily make them the same as the ones from the API you're using. You could quite easily return a failure indication (true = fail, false = success) which would make your code the much nicer looking:

```
return something_failed;
```

or, at worst,

```
if (something_failed) return TRUE;
: : :
return FALSE;
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not ok, at least not until you know how NT_SUCCESS is defined.
It can be defined as `#define NT_SUCCESS 1` or as `#define NT_SUCCESS TRUE`

In the second case it makes sense to write `!NT_SUCCESS`, so your code is ok, but in the first case, writing `!NT_SUCCESS` means `!1`, which doesn't make any sense. In the second case you would be better off with:

```
#define SUCCESS NT_SUCCESS
#define FAILURE -1 //or other value which makes sense
```

It's up to you.

Comment: !1 makes perfect sense. It's 0. !x is defined as 0 if x is nonzero, and 1 if x is 0.

Comment: #define NT_SUCCESS ENT_NOERR /* synonym of ENT_NOERR */

Comment: I have just checked how it is defined. So NT_SUCCESS is set to 0. 
So I guess !NT_SUCCESS is the same as !0. Would this be correct to do what I have done with my marcos?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be truly paranoid, you should add parentheses:

```
#define FAILURE (!NT_SUCCESS)
```

Comment: What difference would adding parentheses do? Thanks.

Comment: In general, it's recommended to use parentheses when defining macros so that you don't get unexpected results due to simple textual substitution combined with operator precedence.

Comment: @robUK: You should spend some time reading through the comp.lang.c FAQ.  In particular: http://c-faq.com/cpp/safemacros.html

Comment: @James. Thanks. At the time I thought maybe it was ok as it was just one operator. Thanks for correcting me.

Comment: -1: I'm not sure why you wouldn't delete this post and just upvote/comment on Lira's instead, she obviously had the same answer as you, before you....

Comment: -1 from me...LiraNuna answered first before you! Don't embellish and improvise other people's answers to get a rep gain for your own gain!

Comment: @gnarf - our two answers were posted 26 seconds apart.  Yes, it would have been better for me to have noticed it and then deleted my answer.

Comment: @tommieb75 - our two answers were posted 26 second apart.  I think it's more likely that I answered independently and didn't notice her answer.